# .htaccess not working on ip/~username

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my case. I'm trying to use .htaccess for rewrite url, but no matter how I try, browser always show 500 error or 404 error.

here is my code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~torinots/beta/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(/beta/home)
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]
```

example path: http://xx.xx.xx.xx/~username/beta/

Pls advice.

**Update**

I found this work!

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /~torinots
>   RewriteRule ^beta/home/?$ beta/index.php [L,NC]

Comment: I assume the url you want to show is ~username/beta? What is the url you want to rewrite to (or in other words: What is the file you want to execute)?

Comment: Hi, I want to rewrite "index.php" to "home",the full path will be http://110.40.40.40/~username/beta/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the .htaccess file in /~username/beta, since you use paths relative to that in the example above. Having a simple rule like the following rule will correctly internally rewrite the url, assuming that no other rules in .htaccess files higher up are interfering.

```
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]
```

If you want to redirect a request to index.php too, then you need to prevent an infinite loop from happening. You can either use the END-flag (version 2.3.9 and up) or the THE_REQUEST trick.

```
#internal rewrite, and then stop everything
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [END]

#Rewritebase is possibly needed for the redirect
RewriteBase /~torinots/beta/

#external redirect
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ home [R=301,L]
```

or:

```
#internal rewrite, and then stop everything
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]

#Rewritebase is possibly needed for the redirect
RewriteBase /~torinots/beta/

#external redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ home [R=301,L]
```